# Aggregate on one filed and horizontal table on other

Tags: r, data-mining

I have a dataset with various fileds and I want to aggregate it on 1 column and horizontally tabulize on other columns

```
Region  Device
a   ios
a   chrome
a   safari
a   ios
a   chrome
b   chrome
b   chrome
b   safari
c   ios
c   chrome
c   ios
```

I want the output to be like

```
Region  ios Chrome  safari
a   2   2   1
b   0   2   1
c   2   1   0
```

My end motive is to make tabular as well as graphical representations

Comment: Region Device
a ios
a chrome
a safari
a ios
a chrome
b chrome
b chrome
b safari
c ios
c chrome
c ios

Comment: Try `table(df$Region, df$Device)` (if you data is stored in a dataframe called df)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format

Answer (score 0):

Using base R:

```
> dat
   Region Device
1       a    ios
2       a chrome
3       a safari
4       a    ios
5       a chrome
6       b chrome
7       b chrome
8       b safari
9       c    ios
10      c chrome
11      c    ios
> xtabs(s~Region+Device,cbind(dat,s=1))
      Device
Region chrome ios safari
     a      2   2      1
     b      2   0      1
     c      1   2      0
```

Using reshape2 package:

```
> library(reshape2)
> dcast(dat,Region~Device,length,value.var="Device")
  Region chrome ios safari
1      a      2   2      1
2      b      2   0      1
3      c      1   2      0
>
```